# html form, add to php link

Tags: php, html, forms

i need to make a form like this:

```
    <form name="input" action="" method="POST">

Code: <input type="text" name="code"><br><br>
<input type="submit"><br>

</form><br><br>
```

and when i  press Submit what to add that "Code" to the following link:
http://website.com/display_code_info.php?code=

like when someone types 123456789 in Form Code area Link Like this apear on submit:
http://website.com/display_code_info.php?code=123456789

Thank to answers, it worked!

**now how can i open that php page in popup frame in page without showin that address?**

Comment: Simple: `method="GET"` attribute on the form tag.

Comment: you want to show code on the next page?

Comment: @user3514075, what do you want do with this url? Why do you want this number as a GET variable?

Comment: when you do this kind of way it is not secure just FYI.

Comment: is it action URL or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code will be

```
 <form name="input" action="display_code_info.php" method="GET">

Code: <input type="text" name="code"><br><br>
<input type="submit"><br>

</form>
```

Comment: This is a correct anwser too - but I guess the guy that asked for an answer even do not know the difference between GET and POST. Otherwise he would just catch the POST data in the script he uses.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL appears to want a `$_GET`, but you're sending `POST`.

Fortunately, a POST is better suited for this kind of task. Are you in control of that URL? Then look in the `$_POST` variables.

If not, and you want it like this, change your form to `method="GET"` and your `action=` to the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , we can't go to that link. Second , we're not here to make your stuff. This place is to ask for help when you get stuck on something more specific.

Now we have that out of the way, you need the following.

The page that has your form , index.php for example :

```
<form name="myFormName" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="myInput">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The action is set to process.php , so make a file with that name and make it do this :

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

It will output everything it has received from the form , instead of dumping it like that you can obviously do other things with the data. If you want the values from the form to appear in the url of the website , you need to use `method = "GET"` in the form and `$_GET` in the php file instead of `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code.

```
<form name="input" action="http://website.com/display_code_info.php" method="GET">
```

put your required page url in action attribute and change the method to 'GET' instead of 'POST'

Answer (score 0):

Html code

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post">
    ...
    </form>


 php code

<?php
   echo "";// print your desire value
?>
```